# Copyrights of recorded lectures?

Tags: copyright, lecturer, intellectual-property, audio-video-recording

Most universities around the world are now requesting their lecturers to record lectures and post them on a repository. In my university, we use Moodle to store and share video recordings.

My question is: what are the copyirights of my uploaded videos (say in UK and/or USA)? Do I have any rights once I upload my videos to the system?

My question is motivated by a big discussion we are currently having in our Faculty (where Faculty means a group of Science Departments) on whether the University has total rights on our uploaded videos. If so, they want to recycle lectures even after lecturers leave (say, for another university) or die.

I understand this can be seen as one of those questions whose answer is: check your contract, ask your manager, read the entire Constitution, ... My question relates to a general understanding of copyrights of video lectures. Thanks.

Comment: Copyright law varies. It is unlikely to be the same in all details between US and UK.

Comment: To those voting to close: I hope not every question that might have different answers in different countries is banned as "depends on individual factors".

Comment: I don't think this is the right place to ask. This is: https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is an interesting question, but probably the correct answer would be rather complex. In the EU, I would assume that also the General Data Protection Regulation has some relevance when it comes to using video or voice recordings. Although neither valid for the US or the UK, something similar might exist? At my university in the EU, I upload my recordings without being aware of having signed away any rights in this direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you, the faculty, want to retain any rights, I suggest that you (as a collective group negotiating with the administration) write them into a contract. You might be able to come to a royalty agreement, but I doubt much beyond that.

If faculty are employees of the university then most of the IP created can be claimed by the employer, just as if you were employed by IBM in a research capacity.

I don't think that universities (none in my experience) get in the way of a faculty member publishing books (or software, ...), but those are normally written at the full initiative of the author(s) rather than at the direction of the university. And since there are other alternatives for teaching a course than writing your own book, it is normally an independent activity. Lectures, however, like other explicit course materials, seem to be in a different category.

The course materials were created by yourself, but at the direction of the employer. The university provides the infrastructure and the audience.

IANAL, but guess that the above is a pretty general interpretation. Copyright law, however, is variable around the world and to some extent, so is the relationship between the faculty and the university. So, "your mileage may vary."

Absent a formal agreement, the university will probably claim to own all rights including the rights to reuse such things in the future whether the faculty member is employed there or not and without additional compensation. It would be difficult, at best, to contest this view, I think.

I would prefer a different interpretation, of course, in which the law would recognize that the faculty *is* the university and derives all function and authority from the consent and participation of the faculty. However, that is a late medieval view. Yes, I'm that old.

If a university wants to maintain a high quality faculty and keep them happy and productive, I think they would be willing to negotiate some sharing arrangement. It would need to be formalized. An argument for such an agreement would, I think, be an improvement in the general quality of such things.

Comment: Very interesting points.  I have clarified the meaning of 'Faculty" in my question, as in this case it means a group of Science Departments (e.g. Faculty of Sciences). I think in the USA, faculty means staff members in charge of teaching and research.

Comment: We use the same terminology here, actually.  I use it in both senses.

Comment: But the negotiation and agreement I suggest here needs to be collective (Faculty vs faculty), not individually worked out. That would be logistically impossible, I think.

Answer (score 0):

In the United States, and possibly in all Berne Convention nations, copyright exists in a creative work as soon as it is "fixed in a tangible medium."  Sound and video recordings qualify as fixed in a tangible medium.

In general, copyright belongs to the person who created the work.  The exception is a "work made for hire," which belongs to the person or organization doing the hiring.  In the United States, for something to be a work made for hire requires an agreement beforehand.  In the absence of such an agreement, the work belongs to the person who created it.

<strike>So, in the absence of a "work made for hire" clause in your contract, you own the copyright to your recorded lectures.</strike> Well, *that* was wrong.  In the U.S., an employment relationship seems to classify work done in the course of employment as "work made for hire."  Sorry.

Enforcing such a copyright may be a different matter entirely.

Comment: Have you assumed that the individual has "made" the work? That is to say, recored it and fixed it... Or is that something that was done by the university. And, does being "required" to record it and the individual complying imply an "agreement" even if assumed rather than written?

Comment: @Buffy  I've assumed the individual faculty member "made" the work, in the same sense that Taylor Swift "makes" her recordings and not the rented recording studio.  The original question says "requested" rather than "required."  In the United States and in the midst of a pandemic, a university could probably get away with "required."  In more normal times, I doubt it unless part of a contract.  It's a legal, not academic, question, but I'd argue that the copyright still belongs to the faculty member.  I might even put a copyright notice on my recordings and See What Happens.™

Comment: Tough guy. While I agree that is how it should be, the professor doesn't "rent the studio". That studio doesn't employ Ms. Swift, quite the other way round. But, I await the outcome of your copyright suit. I hope you prevail.

Comment: The work for hire exception is also country-dependent. E.g. in Germany, the employee will always keep the full copyright and there is no legal way to give it away. There will however likely be a clause in the work contract granting (possibly exclusive) usage rights to the employer.

Comment: The positive here is that it defines when copyright comes to existence.